# Copy kubernetes pod's repository directly to azure storage account

Tags: azure, kubernetes, xargs, azure-storage-account, azcopy

I'm trying to copy pod's repository directly to azure storage account using a pipe.

Instead of doing these two commands :

```
kubectl cp my_pod:my_repository/ . -n my_namespace
azcopy cp my_repository/ "https://my-storage.blob.core.windows.net/?sp=r..." --recursive=true
```

I would like to do something like this using "--from-to" azcopy parameter :

```
kubectl cp my_pod:my_repository/ -n my_namespace | azcopy cp "https://my-storage.blob.core.windows.net/?sp=r..." --from-to PipeBlob --recursive=true
```

Not sure if it's possible. maybe with xargs ?

I Hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: What is the benefit of doing it in one line? just wondering

Comment: because I'm missing disk space on the VM from which I do the copy so I'm looking for a way to just copy and paste my folder straight to the destination

Comment: AFAIK the only solution, in this case, is doing `azcopy` directly from the pod. I am not sure how viable that is.